# Installing/enabling PHP Pecl Intl extension on CentOs 5

Tags: centos, installation, pecl, php

## Original question:

I'm having trouble installing the PHP Pecl Intl extension on my CentOs 5 machine.

After installing both `icu` and `libicu` with the following commands:

```
$ yum install icu
$ yum install libicu
```

I tried to install the Intl extension like so:

```
$ /usr/bin/pecl install intl
```

I selected to search for the default location for the ICU libraries and header files.
It ends up crashing like this:

```
checking whether to enable internationalization support... yes, shared
checking for icu-config... no
checking for location of ICU headers and libraries... not found
configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed
```

## update

After successfully installing the development version of icu as suggested by [RusAlex](https://serverfault.com/questions/210889#answer-210893) (thanks RusAlex) like so:

```
$ yum install libicu-devel
```

I ran into a new problem which I also encountered locally the following command:

```
$ /usr/bin/pecl install intl
```

now produces this error:

```
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:92: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:96: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:101: error: duplicate 'static'
 /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:107: error: duplicate 'static'
 make: *** [collator/collator_class.lo] Error 1
 ERROR: `make' failed
```

It appears to have something to do with PHP 5.3 being bundled with Intl already. But how can I enable this extension, if I look in my PHP Info than I cannot find any reference to it...

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo yum install libicu
sudo yum install libicu-devel.x86_64
sudo /usr/bin/pecl install intl
sudo echo 'extension=intl.so' >> /etc/php.ini
```

And you are good to go. And better enter the extension=intl.so manually to php.ini or even more elegant create a new .ini file in the /etc/php.d/ directory.

Comment: Worked for me. Centos 5.8 x86_64 with CPanel.

Comment: for me , on line 3 : sudo /usr/bin/pecl install intl  it says 'command not found' , am  I missing something please ?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct, you can't install the PECL package because [as of PHP 5.3 Intl is part of PHP](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16031).

If you installed PHP using YUM, you can just pull down the intl package:

```
> yum list php*intl
> yum install <file_from_above>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on CentOS 5.6:

```
yum install gcc gcc-cpp gcc-c++
```

After that all errors to do with `intl` disappeared

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to install `icu-dev` or `icu-devel` package or something similar.

You need development package.

Comment: Thanks, that got me a little further, I've updated the post accordingly. Just for the sake of reference: the command to install the development version I used is `$ yum install libicu-devel`

Answer (score 1):

1. `/usr/bin/pecl install intl`
2. Search log `checking for icu-config... /usr/bin/icu-config*`.
   You'll need a path of the directory which has `/bin/icu-config` later.
3. Download php:

   `wget http://us2.php.net/get/php-5.3.6.tar.gz/from/jp.php.net/mirror`

   `tar xvzf php-5.3.6.tar.gz`

   `cd php-5.3.6/ext/intl/`
4. compile and install intl module.
   phpize

   `./configure --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/usr`

   `make`

   `make test`

   `sudo make install`
5. Finally, append `extension=intl.so` into `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is

```
yum install libicu-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have gcc, gcc-cpp, and gcc-c++ installed... At least that was one of my issues during install - http://itblogspot.net/php-install-intl

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on CentOS, and I successfully installed **INTL** via **pecl** after:

1) install icu & libs:

```
yum -y install icu libicu libicu-devel
```

2) php-devel package and phpize:

```
yum -y install php-devel phpize
```

3) and, of course gcc:

```
yum -y install gcc gcc-cpp gcc-c++
```

(+1 to yuri for gcc, gcc-cpp, and gcc-c++ , sorry can't comment due to no rating  )